# Ubuntu 18.04 (new laptop) wifi connects but no internet

Tags: wireless, 18.04, acer, atheros

I've just bought an Acer Aspire 7 and I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I can get access to the internet through a wired connection but when it comes to wifi it looks to be connected to mine but there's no actual internet access. I'm not sure why I can't get it.
 I've got this:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: 00:f4:8d:6c:24:cd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-43-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:128 memory:a4200000-a43fffff
```

Might it be that I need some drivers or something, if so, what?

EDIT. iwconfig gives me the following (if it's any help):

```
~$ iwconfig
enp3s0f1  no wireless extensions.

enp0s20f0u6  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TheMagi"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:1F:C6:81:BB:0E   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:100   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: I would bet the issue is with Network Manager enabling power manager for wifi

Comment: No, I checked that and it wasn't the issue. Thanks though.